# Template default argument as a pointer to itself

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, default

I am trying to develop a generic tree template class, basically, representing a hierarchy of identical nodes. It takes 2 template arguments, the first one is a data, and the second - a type which would reference another node (prev,next,parent,child). By default, I want it to be a conventional pointer to the node, but for my purpose I also need it to be something different (e.g an integer index into the memory pool). The code below does not compile. Instinctively, I feel it can be done, but I don't know how. Could anyone provide an insight into this?

```
template <typename U, typename TPTR = TreeNode_t<U>*>
class TreeNode_t
{
public:
    TPTR    prev;
    TPTR    next;
    TPTR    parent;
    TPTR    children;
    U m;
public:
    TreeNode_t() : prev(0), next(0), parent(0){}
    ~TreeNode_t(){}
    U &data() { return m; }
    const U &data() const { return m; }
    ...
```

To be specific, in general I instantiate it like this:

```
TreeNode_t<double> tree1;
```

But, sometimes I would like it this way:

```
TreeNode_t<double, unsigned> tree2;
```

Comment: it would be `TreeNode_t<U, TreeNode_t<U, TreeNode_t<U, TreeNode_t<U>, ...>>>`...

Answer (score 5):

provide a special default as `void` and use type inside the class:

```
template <typename U, typename TPTR = void>
class TreeNode_t
{
    using NodeType = std::conditional_t<std::is_same<void, TPTR>::value, TreeNode_t*, TPTR>;
public:
    NodeType    prev;
    NodeType    next;
    NodeType    parent;
    NodeType    children;
    U m;
// ...
};
```

Comment: Looks like to be a perfectly valid solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two type parameters as the pointer can be deduced from the base type. Of course TreeNode_t is not defined before the template thus it doesn't compile.

```
template <typename U>
    class TreeNode_t
    {
    public:
        TreeNode_t<U>*    prev;
        TreeNode_t<U>*    next;
        TreeNode_t<U>*    parent;
        TreeNode_t<U>*    children;
    //...
```

Comment: No, as  I have stated, a 'pointer' to a node may not be a pointer at all.